# bms-push cordova plugin on iOS gives: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I've implemented an Ionic test application using the new [bms-push](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push) cordova plugin.

It works fine on Android.

However, when launching the app on iOS, it immediately fails with:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The error occurs in the `didReceiveRemoteNotificationOnLaunch` function of the `CDVBMSPush` class.

If I comment out the following line in the AppDelegate.m

`[[CDVBMSPush sharedInstance] didReceiveRemoteNotificationOnLaunchWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];`

then the app starts properly.

Any suggestion to fix the problem please?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got an [answer](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push/issues/55) from the support team:

> `[[CDVBMSPush sharedInstance] didReceiveRemoteNotificationOnLaunchWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];`
>
> This is only used when app is opened by clicking push notifications.
>
> At the first time launchOptions will be nil. That why its failing.
>
> **Solutions:**
>
> 1. you can add a check there whether the launchOptions is of type remoteNotificationKey, If yes then add the `[[CDVBMSPush sharedInstance] didReceiveRemoteNotificationOnLaunchWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];`
>
> *Example*:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
      [[CDVBMSPush sharedInstance] didReceiveRemoteNotificationOnLaunchWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    }
}
```

> 2. Completely remove that line of code.

Comment: I'm getting a crash that is pointing to this line of code too.. but only when launched via the TestFlight app. The BMS-Push example/setup code has been updated a bit to include a check for nil but I'm still getting the error so have gone for removal of the line. I'll let you know if it works.